# Excel import to SQL via VBA (Run-Time Error)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, runtime-error, import-from-excel

I am trying to import via a VBA button a ton of Excel data (around 30k + daily) into an existing table in SQL server. My question is how can I do this as simple as possible, code speaking?
The headers both in my Excel file and SQL table are 1:1 the same so I just want to import everything into the SQL table

This is what I started to write but when I try to make the code work I get a "Run-time error '-2147217865 (80040e37): Invalid object name "dbo.Rawdata".

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("A6:DA269239")
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;" & _
        "Server =localhost\name" & _
        "Database =name;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    
    con.Open
    
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim strn_reference As String
    Dim batchInsert As String
    
    Dim batchSize As Integer
    batchSize = 1000
    
    iRowNo = 0
    For Each cl In r
        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        batchInsert = batchInsert + (IIf(iRowNo > 1, ",", "")) + "('" & Replace(cl.Value2, "'", "''") & "')"
         If (iRowNo = batchSize) Then
             con.Execute "insert into dbo.Rawdata (trn_reference) Values " & batchInsert
             iRowNo = 0
             batchInsert = ""
         End If
     Next
     If Len(batchInsert) > 0 Then con.Execute "insert into dbo.Rawdata (trn_reference) Values " & batchInsert


    MsgBox "Reference Numbers imported"
 
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: The loop does work for me. As soon as `iRowNo` reaches `1000` the `if` branch also runs and `iRowNo` will be reset to `0`.

Comment: hmm interesting that it works for you. I tested it again with a Debugger and it says that he actually has a problem with the "con.Execute "insert into dbo.Rawdata..." and i get a run-time error -2147217865 (80040e37): Invalid object name "dbo.Rawdata".
Any idea what this could be ?

Comment: I am afraid but that is a different problem now.  Please edit your post accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I edited the post (correctly hopefully) :) I am sorry if I was unclear before, I am quite new to SQL and this platform also

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should refer to the table name from SQL server not **dbo.Rawdata** but directly:

`Rawdata|"Insert into Rawdata(column_name) VALUES ('" & vba_variable & "')"`

This should be the SQL statement from VBA.

This work for me very well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I will test it in my code and see if anything changes. If i understood correctly this part should look like this or ?       If (iRowNo = batchSize) Then
             con.Execute "insert into Rawdata (column_name) Values ('" & vba_variable & "') batchInsert"
             iRowNo = 0
             batchInsert = ""             Sorry if I understood wrong, I am quite new to writing code, hope you can understand!

Comment: batchinsert should be the vba_variable this should be the execute code `"insert into Rawdata (column_name) Values ('" & batchinsert  & "')"`      if your batchinsert is a number datatype (integer, BigInteger, etc) then after values you should put `"( ' & batchinsert & ')"`

Comment: Now it seems to work better but it still has a problem with the con.Execute line...i have way to many columns to declare in the (column_name) part and if I delete that part it asks me for parameters (no value given for one or more required parameters).

Comment: if you have more columns, that put them separated with comma `INSERT INTO Rawdata (Column1,Column2,etc) VALUES (Column1Value,Volumn2Value,etc)`, if you do not put any column name, then you should go with `INSERT INTO Rawdata ValueFor1stColumn,ValueFor2ndColumn,etc` you need to put values separated with comma for each column in table (except identified columns, ID column in most cases, and calculated columns, or default value)